# audio tag working in ie8 except when bound to onclick event

Tags: javascript

I am having some trouble getting an mp3 file to play in IE8 when bound to an image with an onclick event. I have plenty of audio on the site that plays on autoplay in many browsers but when the user clicks on the image to hear an audio file, it won't play. Also, I am synching the audio to jquery animations if that may be conflicting with the code. The code follows, thanks in advance to anyone who may be able to shed some light on my problem.

```
<img onclick="document.getElementById('call-1a').play()" id="keypad" class="float-left" src="IMG/graph.gif" alt="" />
```

Comment: IE8 doesn't support `<audio>` elements : http://caniuse.com/audio ...

Comment: I understand that IE8 doesn't support the audio tag, but it works with audio.js. And it plays very nicely until I bind it to an onclick event like the example above. It appears to me that it has trouble playing the audio file when javascript is involved. Anybody else have any thoughts? They would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: audiojs doesn't magically add methods to elements. It provides an API for playing audio. The `play` method is some available in browsers that support `<audio>` elements. You should be using the audiojs API to play the file. If you look at https://github.com/kolber/audiojs/blob/master/demos/test6.html , you should see the `var as = audiojs.createAll(), audio = as[0]`, which I'm pretty sure initializes any, and gets a handle on the first (only) `<audio>` (the `audio` variable). Then later, it uses `audio.setVolume()`, which I'm sure you could use `audio.play()` instead